# Eclipse Juno Open Resource Camel Case failing for classes ending with numbers

Tags: java, eclipse, camelcasing

I've made a few failed attempts to file a bug for Eclipse - any suggestion?

This is a great time-saver opening classes in Eclipse but now there's a bug in my way...

I use camel case shortcuts in Open Resource all the time.   Now in the JUNO version this feature isn't working for classes that end in digits.  Example class FooBar123 - this should appear when I type FB1.  Instead it appears with others when I type FB but as soon as I add a digit to further qualify it no longer appears.

This worked in HELIOS and earlier versions.

The numbers here correspond to existing application identifiers - there are over a hundred; now I'm forced back to the mouse to scroll and select... or I have to type the whole class name preceding the number e.g. FooBar1

Comment: what took you  so long to hit the bug? Juno is more than 4 years old! does Neon have the bug too? Did you file a bug report at bugzilla?

Comment: Even if you could submit a bug, there is no chance of it getting fixed in such an old version. If it's reproducible in a latest release, yes; but they won't backport it to something that's 3-4 years old.

Comment: This seems to work fine in Eclipse Neon.1